# Passing file to Docker service in GitHub Actions

Tags: docker, github-actions

I am trying to pass env-file from GitHub Actions folder to Docker service but I can't figure out how to do it. Below is what I did so far, but it doesn't work.

GitHub Actions job:

```yaml
  job-name:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: node:16-bullseye
    services:
      backend:
        image: backend:latest
        options: --env-file ./workflows/backend-dependencies/.env
```

where my folder structure is:

```
- myservice
  - .github
    - workflows
      - backend-dependencies
        - .env
      -  job.yaml
```

What I get is `docker: open ./workflows/backend-dependencies/.env: no such file or directory.`

Comment: The service is being set up before your code is checked out to the build environment.

Comment: Okay, good point, but "steps" will be executed after "services" anyway, right? So it would still be the same or?